# Notepad++ regex replace the last words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have sentences like this:

> {Hello, I am Jeng|I am Jong|I am Jien.} {Hello, I am Keng|I am Kong|I
>   am Kien.}

How to replace the last ".}" by .|} ? Thank you very much !

So, the result:

> {Hello, I am Jeng|I am Jong|I am Jien.} {Hello, I am Keng|I am Kong|I
>   am Kien.|}

Comment: Read the instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have "Regular Expressions" checked in the replace dialog.

Find:     `\.\}$`
Replace:  `|}`

Both the period and the bracket need to be escaped since they are regex special characters.

[RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/) is one of the many regex places that you could ( and should visit ) to learn more.

Comment: great ! It works like a charm ! Can I ask 1 more question: How to replace last "{" ? Thanks !